# Taylor series of f(x + a) becomes exponential

Tags: taylor-expansion, exponential-function

In my symmetries of classical mechanics course we have looked at taylor expansions. Our notes claim that;
$$
f(x + a) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} f^{(n)}(x)a^n ≡ \exp{\left( a \frac{d}{dx}\right)} f(x)
$$
I am happy with the first equality, its explained quite nicely in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254792/how-is-the-taylor-expansion-for-fx-h-derived). The second equality is puzzling though. I dont even know what to make of the derivative inside the exponent.

How is the second equality derived?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It applies the exponential function $\exp(y) = \sum \frac{1}{n!}y^n$ to the [differential operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator) $a\frac{d}{dx}$ to give $$\exp\left(a\frac{d}{dx}\right) = \sum \frac{1}{n!}a^n \frac{d^n}{dx^n}.$$ This, when applied to $f(x)$, gives your middle expression.

Comment: My question might seem stupid, but what is the meaning of $\exp(D)$ ? It is natural to say that : $\displaystyle \exp(D) \; \mathop{=} \limits^{\mathrm{def}} \; \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{D^{n}}{n!}$ but I'm wondering in which space this series is converging, for which topology.

Comment: I second jibounet's question!