# Different form of Taylor series in Leibniz Notation

Tags: derivatives, notation, power-series, taylor-expansion

I have already seen some posts about a different way to write a Taylor series of a smooth function $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow  \mathbb{R}  $, but all of them are written using the lagrange notation for derivative, $f'(x)$, and I'm trying to develop the same formula in the leibniz notation $\frac{d}{dx} f(x)$. Here's my attempt:

Suppose $f$ is a one-variable function smooth at  some point $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then its Taylor series around $x$ is given by

$$ f(y) = f(x) + (y-x)\frac{d}{dy}[f(y)] \Bigg|_{y=x} + \frac{1}{2!}(y-x)^2 \frac{d^2}{dy^2} [f(y)] \Bigg|_{y=x} + \cdots$$

If $\epsilon := y-x \implies f(y) = f(x + (y-x)) = f(x+\epsilon)$, such that

$$ f(x+\epsilon) = f(x)+ \epsilon\frac{d}{dy}[f(y)]+\Bigg|_{y=x} + \frac{1}{2!}\epsilon^2 \frac{d^2}{dy^2} [f(y)] \Bigg|_{y=x} + \cdots $$

If I state that $\frac{d^n}{dy^n} [f(y)] \Bigg|_{y=x} \equiv \frac{d^n}{dx^n} [f(x)]$, the taylor series is

$$ f(x+\epsilon) = f(x)+ \epsilon\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]+ \frac{1}{2!}\epsilon^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2} [f(x)]  + \cdots$$

Is this notation for changing the variable in the derivatives from $y$ to $x$ confusing?

*Note: I know how to proceed using Lagrange notation for derivatives, my problem is due exclusively to Leibniz notation.*

Comment: If you state that $y$ is some free parameter before this derivation, it shouldn't be confusing. If you don't, one could assume that $y=f(x)$ and so $f(y)$ = $f(f(x))$, which is not what you mean. Besides that, everything looks fine. Your derivation is [identical](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/254799/695196) to the one you get if you use Lagrange's notation. Different notation shouldn't change a thing. If you denote the derivative as $f', \dot{f}, Df, \frac{df}{dx}$ or any other notation you want, you're still saying the exact same thing.